# How to style span tag of option text in html select

Tags: html, html-select

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-pynxnd?file=index.html)

I have a scenario where the first option of my HTML select includes an asterisk which is supposed to be in a red color. However I am unable to style the asterisk and it always appears in the default black color.

I have included the stackblitz example and even if i use an image of asterisk it still does not work as intended.

Comment: You got some code?

Comment: The stackblitz link seems to be broken

Comment: The stackblitz link is provided. Also it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just style the span tag, because only plain text can be placed in the option element.
So actually there is no span tag.
[image]
But you can add style to select, and color will be red in select element.

```css
select {
  color: red;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://web-platform-h8grjw.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Yes that is what I have seen for the past few hours of me trying to find a way to achieve this. Looks like it might just not be possible.